# How to add new label to Gmail based on previous labels + specific string

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'm trying to configure some automation when it comes to labeling my Gmail mailbox.
Currently, I want to apply label "X" to every new message that match the specific string "abc" and DON'T have label "Y".

The problem I'm facing is that whenever someone responds to old thread with label "Y", the filter is being triggered and this mail have to labels "X" and "Y".

TLDR: I don't want to label threads with specific label, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Gmail, labels can be nested, so organized in a tree structure: As labels prepared in advance, as rather static objects, manually.
2. If I understand you correctly:

   - you want the dynamic creation of new labels? ..based on the data from the incoming emails?
   - And even more: In the same moment a new filter-instance to be created for the dynamic-labels, so the new-data emails to be labeled by their respective labels. Probably to define not a "static filter", but rather a filter template, with placeholders, for parsed values? ..i.e. via filter-template-regEx?

There is no such feature in Gmail, AFAIK.

I can imagine such feature, i.e. for notification emails from a ticketing systems like Jira or eBay... But I have never heard about such feature in Gmail. Not for/in any mail client at all.